PL\SQL loop block with sleep, hangs if not completed in 1 minute
I have a PL/SQL stored procedure that, during its execution, needs to wait for a Java process to finish and write a record to a table. To achieve this result, I used a while loop to check for the presence of the required record and included a 1 second sleep if the record is still not present. The problem arises when the record takes longer than a minute to get inserted into the table; in such cases, the loop seems to hang indefinitely, and the procedure fails to proceed.
I can confirm the 1 minute time limit because I log messages before and after the loop, allowing me to track its execution. I've tried to diagnose any hanging executions by monitoring queries in v$session and v$sql, but given the high frequency of procedure calls, I find it challenging to pinpoint the issue.
Why does the procedure hang in such cases?
This is the code:
WHILE w_tmp > 0  
LOOP     
       -- Get the last job in execution and get the last event registered from that job                
       select event_type
       into w_event_type
       from log_jobs
       where log_jobs.id_job = (select max(id_job) from jobs where job_type = 'C')
       order by id_log desc
       fetch first row only;
        
       IF w_event_type = 'JOB_OK' THEN
                                  
              --EXIT;
              w_tmp := 0;

       ELSE
                    
              DBMS_SESSION.SLEEP(1);
                
       END IF;
END LOOP;

Other information:

Oracle version is 19C.
The procedure is called from another procedure inside a package that waits for its completion.
Both the calling procedure and the procedure in question have the AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION pragma.

Thank you.
PS: using the EXIT statement with the 1 = 1 loop clause produce the same results.
